# If $Ext_A^n(M,N) \ne 0$, then $Ext_A^n(M,N') \ne 0$, for every indecomposable summand N' of N?

Tags: modules, homological-algebra

Let $A$ be an artin algebra and $M$ and $N$ finitely generated modules over $A$. Suppose that $Ext_A^n(M,N) \ne 0$, is it possible to conclude that $Ext_A^n(M,N') \ne 0$, for each indecomposable summand $N'$ of $N$?

Comment: Find any $N'$ such that $Ext^n_A(M,N') = 0$. Now find any $N''$ such that $Ext^n_A(M,N') \neq 0$. Then consider $N = N' \oplus N''$. You have a counterexample to your assertion.

Comment: @Amit ty!!  If we had the following situation: $M$ has projection dimension $2$ else exists $0 \to K \to P_1 \to P_0 \to M \to 0$ where $K$ is kernel of $P_1 \to P_0$. Let $Ext^3 (M,K) \neq 0$. Why for every indecomposable summand $N'$ of $K$, $Ext^3 (M,N') \neq 0$?

Comment: Sorry, its $Ext^2_A (M,K) \neq 0$ and $Ext^2_A (M,N') \neq 0$.